# Select numbers by their first n digits

Tags: ruby

I have an array of numbers:

```
array = [234, 928234, 234932]
```

I need to count how many of the elements in `array` have the first three digits as `234`; i.e., the result should count in `array[0]` and `array[2]`.

Is there a way to use `.count`? If I use `array.count("234")`, it will count in all elements. Is there something I can add to `array.count{ }` to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to stringify each element before you can make that kind of comparison:

```
[234, 928234, 234932].count { |num| num.to_s.start_with? '234' }
```

See also: [`String#start_with?`](http://rubydoc.info/docs/ruby-core/1.9.2/String#start_with%3F-instance_method)

Comment: Thanks, now what if I needed the number that was being compared to be variable. For example if I always wanted the the first number in the array to be compared to the rest in the array, say now its array = [432, 234532, 25532, 432564] . so instead of looking for '234' like above it now needs to compare '432'. How would you make it compare array[0] to the others?

Comment: @MattC. something like this i guess: `array.count { |number| number.to_s.start_with? array.first.to_s }`

Answer (score 1):

[`Integer#digits`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-digits) returns an [`Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html) of [`Integer`s](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html) representing the digits of an `Integer`. The digits are returned least-significant place first, so what you'll want to do is look at the *last* three elements of the `Array` and compare them to `[4, 3, 2]`:

```
array.count {|n| n.digits[-3..-1] == [4, 3, 2] }
#=> 2
```

Comment: The best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like Jorg is doing you can pass a block to #count and in that block convert the number to a string then use simple string match.

```
array = [234, 928234, 234932, 234444234, 234, 2345]
array.count{|x| x.to_s.match(/^234/)}
5
```